# Why does the append operation in Python work slow down when appending large strings?

Tags: python, append

When you run the following code, append times take 10 times longer as time goes on.

```
from datetime import datetime

test = []

for i in range(30000):
    time_before_append = datetime.now()
    test.append("testeafda" * 100000)
    time_after_append = datetime.now()
    print(time_after_append - time_before_append)
```

I understand that append is generally O(1). Does this relate to garbage collection, the list resizing itself, memory usage and/or something else? Just trying to understand how the internals of Python work.

Comment: That's like 30 gigabytes of strings you're building there. Do you even have 30 gigabytes of RAM?

Comment: You're adding 1 MB of data 30k times in a loop and you're wondering why it's slow? Also, `"testeafda" * 100000` is going to have to rebuild the string 100,000 times since strings are immutable. You'd get an instant speed up if you predefined that string outside the loop and appended it to a list instead of rebuilding each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's from `"testeafda" * 100000` because the a new string is created 10000 times.

Even when you append a character to an existing string, a new string is actually created.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Xrange function (if you are using Python 2.x), that should have a marked improvement in memory management. Like;

```
for i in xrange(30000):
 ...
```

Comment: Compared to the list the OP is trying to build in the loop, a list of 30,000 integers is a drop in the bucket.